# How to mix symbols and text for labels in manipulate?

Tags: plotting, graphics, manipulate, animation, version-7

I'm creating a big manipulate box with several sliders, and each slider must have a small explication text (units, for example) after a mathematical symbol.  As a simple example, here's the code I'm currently using for a slider :

```
{{phi, 0, Style[Subscript[\[CurlyPhi], 0] "(degrees)", Bold, 10]},
    0, 360, 0.1,
    ImageSize -> Large,
    Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}
}
```

Currently, this isn't displayed correctly since it gives **(degrees)phi_0**, instead of **phi_0 (degrees)**.

So what should I do to define a properly displayed symbol with text after it ?

Comment: You have multiplied the subscript and the string, instead use `Row` to format expressions in a row, e.g. `Row[{Subscript[φ, 0], "(degrees)"}]`

Comment: Remember to make all parts a `String` and to join them by `<>`.

Comment: Now, which one is best ?  String or Row ?

Comment: Using Row, how do you change the font size ?

Comment: Argh !  Using **Style** around the **Row**, of course !

Comment: `Style[ToString[Subscript[\[CurlyPhi], 0], TraditionalForm] <> 
  " (degrees)", Bold, 10]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, thanks.  However, **Row** is simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd use `BaseStyle` with `Row` and use `Style` only on pieces which needed their own special style.  I would also protect the `φ` with `HoldForm`.  In general I wrap expressions that contain symbols and are used for labels with `HoldForm`.  It's mainly a habit, because if the symbols happen to have, or later happen to get assigned, values, then the values will mess up the labels.

```
Manipulate[
 phi,
 {{phi, 0, 
   Row[{HoldForm@Subscript[φ, 0], "(degrees)"}, " ", BaseStyle -> {Bold, 10}]},
  0, 360, 0.1, ImageSize -> Large, 
  Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Closed"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I'll mark this answer just because it is showing more options.  These could be usefull.

Comment: @Cham Thanks. Yes there's not much difference between them.  One's preference is, I suppose, a matter of, um, *style*.  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `Style` with `Row` like this

```
Manipulate[
 phi,
 {{phi, 0, Style[Row[{Subscript[φ, 0] , " (degrees)"}], Bold, 10]}, 0, 360, 1, 
    ImageSize -> Large, Appearance -> {"Labeled"}}]
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Both answers are good and merit to be assigned "THE" answer.  Which one should I mark ?